# Enable Exception C++

Tags: android, c++, makefile, cmake, android-ndk

I am trying to make APP native code for Android.
The Native code is in cplusplus.
Whenever I try to make, the following error appears.

> H236Plus.cpp:135: error: exception handling disabled, use -fexceptions to enable

How do I use -fexceptions to enable exception handling, and where do i use it?

Comment: To enable it with ndk-build, use the new LOCAL_CPP_FEATURES variable in your Android.mk, as in:
LOCAL_CPP_FEATURES += exceptions

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to build with CrystaX's [custom NDK](http://crystax.net/android/ndk.php). It has full libstdc++, RTTI and exceptions support. It's generally the best tool for Android development I know.

Answer (score 33):

It depends on what runtime you are using. If you are not using system runtime and are building with `ndk-build`, you add any of these to your Android.mk file:

- LOCAL_CPP_FEATURES += exceptions (Recommended)
- LOCAL_CPPFLAGS += -fexceptions

Also, you can add the following line to your Application.mk file:

- APP_CPPFLAGS += -fexceptions

There's more information in `docs/CPLUSPLUS-SUPPORT.html` in your NDK folder

Answer (score 5):

-fexception is a compiler switch. How you use it depends on your compiler setup. What compiler are you using? IDE? build tool?

Comment: NDK with cygwin. All I did was to type "make APP=project" at cygwin in the directory of ndk folder.

Comment: There should be a Makefile in this directory. This controls how everything is compiled. That's the place to look for compiler switches.

Comment: Is it **-fexception** or **-fexceptions**?

Answer (score 5):

In the compiler flags add -fexception in your Makefile.

Comment: Did that ever worked? With this you'll have -fno-exceptions along with -fexceptions.

Comment: Surely you have to remove the -fno-exceptions to have the -fexceptions take effect?

Answer (score 4):

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3217925/enable-exception-c/20420183#20420183) answer by @Tundebabzy if you are using `ndk-build` build system.

**For [CMake](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cmake.html) build system**

add the following to your module-level `build.gradle` file:

```
android {
  ...
  defaultConfig {
    ...
    externalNativeBuild {

      // For ndk-build, instead use ndkBuild {}
      cmake {
        // Enables exception-handling support.
        cppFlags "-fexceptions"
      }
    }
  }
}
...
```

**For more information** See [this Link](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cpp-support.html#ic).

Comment: Works for me. Also, can use 'ndkBuild' instead of 'cmake'.

Comment: already did; probably in June when I commented

Answer (score 2):

with the latest version of Android Studio this is what my build.gradle looks like:

```
model {
    android {
        compileSdkVersion 23
        buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                shrinkResources false
                proguardFiles.add(file("proguard-rules.txt"))
                signingConfig = $("android.signingConfigs.release")
            }
        }

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "my.android.app"
            minSdkVersion.apiLevel 16
            targetSdkVersion.apiLevel 23
            versionCode 29
            versionName "my.latest.version"
        }

        ndk {
            moduleName "jni-utils"
            ldLibs.add("log")
            cppFlags.add("-std=c++11")
            cppFlags.add("-fexceptions")
            stl "gnustl_static"
        }
    }
    android.signingConfigs {
        create("release") {
            storeFile "C:\\Android\\Git\\MyProject\\keystore\\keystoreCommon"
            storePassword "put you password here"
            keyAlias "put your alias here"
            keyPassword "put your password here"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which part is important? I assume the ndk node. I get error "Cannot invoke method add() on null object" which is for the ldlibs line so I comment that out. Then, I get error "Could not get unknown property 'cppFlags' for object of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.NdkOptions."

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by adding **cFlags "-fexceptions"** into `ndk` section of build.gradle script in `app` or `lib` folder, like this:

```
ndk {
    ...
    cFlags "-fexceptions"
}
```

Update: with a newer Gradle plugin, it goes into `externalNativeBuild`/`cmake` section as follows:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 29

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29

        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags.addAll(["-std=c++11", "-fexceptions", ...])
                ...
            }
        }
    }

...
```

Comment: which build.gradle file? where is this ndk section?

Comment: @steve, I added a few details in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just a note for anyone who has started with one of the NDK examples.

They tend to set `-fno-exceptions` in their CMakeLists.txt, you need to remove it:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS  "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall -Werror -fno-exceptions -frtti")
```

You might want to check whether you want `-Werror` while you're at it.