# can i use throw function on android

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Enable Exception C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3217925/enable-exception-c)

when i use throw function ,like as follow:

```
throw "SobelGradient => cannot allocate memory";
```

this error come out: exception handling disabled, use -fexceptions to enable

And how to solve this error.

Comment: Quite simple: use `-fexceptions`.

Comment: More information.  What's the actual error message?  What's your actual code? (Your code as shown would not compile.)

Comment: Thanks Howard, I have fixed this problem. add -fexceptions compile option

Comment: Is this NDK, Java or what? It wouldn't be legal Java. It might be legal C++ but BIONIC (Android's C/C++ runtime) doesn't support exceptions so the result of using them is likely to be a can of worms. Best idea is probably not to use them at all.

Comment: Hi Howard, it's work when compiling , but not work when linking. which lib should i add

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should in your question mention that this is a NDK problem - otherwise it's quite misleading.
Anyway, if the clue in the comment doesn't help have a look here - seems that this was a similar issue:
[Enable Exception C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3217925/enable-exception-c)

Comment: hi Martin, it work in compling when add -fexceptions compile option. But it did't work when linking. and that's a ndk problem